# Proving an image is a subet of a kernel of a linear map and vice versa

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $B:W\to W$ be a linear map such that $B^2-3B+2I=0$, where $I$ is the identity map on $W$. Prove that $\operatorname{Im}(B-2I)\subseteq\operatorname{Ker}(B-I)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(B-I)\subseteq\operatorname{Ker}(B-2I)$.

I understand that, in this case, $\operatorname{Ker}(B-I)$ will be a vector $u$ in $W$ such that $(B-I)(u)=0_W$, and $\operatorname{Im}(B-2I)$ will be a vector $v$ in $W$ such that $v=(B-2I)(V)$. The same idea will work for the second part of the problem.

But I am struggling to figure out how I would compute the image and kernel in this case as a linear map is quite hard to do computations on. I have tried rearranging the equation given but I am not getting anywhere. Also, I am not entirely sure what a subset is in this case and how I would go about proving it.

So if someone can provide some guidance on how exactly I would compute these images and kernels as well as what the approach should be to prove that they are subsets, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Doesn't $B^2 - 3B + 2I = (B-2I)(B-I) = (B-I)(B-2I) = 0$? Then the result is immediate?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I see that. But how can I use that to compute the image and kernel and also to prove that one is a subset of the other.

Comment: You don't actually need to compute them.

Comment: By the way, your understanding of the concepts of the kernel and image doesn't look right. The kernel of an operator $T$ is **NOT** a vector, but a set of vectors -- all such vectors $v$ that satisfy the condition that $Tv=0$. Similarly, the image is not a single vector, but a certain set of vectors too.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x^2-3x+2=(x-2)(x-1)=(x-1)(x-2)$.

In more detail: the given relation tells us that $(B-I)(B-2I)=B^2-3B+2I=0$ and $(B-2I)(B-I)=B^2-3B+2I=0$ as linear operators.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see this. So does this alone prove the above statements or is a bit more work required? Because I am failing to see how I can apply this to the image and kernel.

Comment: A bit more, but these relations are the key that make it work. For example, let's pick a vector $v\in\operatorname{Im}(B-I)$. By definition it means that $v=(B-I)u$ for some $u\in W$. Then what is $(B-2I)v$?

Comment: Well $(B-2I)v$ will simply be the initial polynomial multiplied by $u$. Will this basically represent the kernel? And since this contains the image as well, the image will be a subset of the kernel?